# Create a photo viewer control in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

How to create a photo viewer in wp7. I have some 10 to 25 images. All these photos are get from a server. I need to download them and show these photos like photoviewer in windows phone. How can I do this? I was tried pivot control, but when it reaches first or last photo it does not stops scrolling. Then I tried a ListBox. but it does not go to next image when scrolling. It may stop in between two images half of each images are shown. I need to work my application exactly like the slide show which is present in windows phone, as its default photoviewer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to create it yourself:

For your Gallery overview you could have something like this:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Tap="ImageTapped">

                        <Image Width="100"
                               Height="100"
                               Margin="5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PictToThumbConverter}}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And to access library you would use:

```
        using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            return library.Pictures.ToList();
        }
```

And converter would look like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var pict = value as Picture;
    if (pict == null) return null;

    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(pict.GetThumbnail());

    return img;
}
```

This should give you a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you could add creationOpitions and create images in background so that the UI thread is not affected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Rad toolkit has a control which suit your need. It will allow you to create a photo gallery same as we see in the photo album of phone.

Comment: can I create a photo gallery without using Telerik toolkit?